# Latency on Redis when call conccurrent command

Tags: redis

I have been investigating the redis latency issue on a couple of weeks, we have more than two years using the redis for store the caches, the issue came up 3 weeks ago. We put the redis and elasticsearch together on the VM google compute using 4vCPU & 24GB of Ram.

Redis info

```
# Server
redis_version:4.0.8
# Clients
connected_clients:99
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0
 Memory
used_memory:214119584
used_memory_human:204.20M
used_memory_rss:278921216
used_memory_rss_human:266.00M
used_memory_peak:2292554800
used_memory_peak_human:2.14G
used_memory_peak_perc:9.34%
used_memory_overhead:16349011
used_memory_startup:765680
used_memory_dataset:197770573
used_memory_dataset_perc:92.70%
total_system_memory:25275248640
total_system_memory_human:23.54G
used_memory_lua:37888
used_memory_lua_human:37.00K
maxmemory:0
maxmemory_human:0B
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.30
mem_allocator:jemalloc-4.0.3
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0
```

This is the current usage
[image]

Here is DBSIZE of redis

```
redis:6379> DBSIZE
(integer) 134934
```

Here is the output of `redis-benchmark` to test GET and SET commands using 0.1 Megabyte value

*localhost means on the vm redis server

[image]

Based on the result of benchmark, I think there is no issue on the network latency.
I can't figure out what is the root cause of the latency

Comment: I have been diagnosing by this guideline https://redis.io/docs/management/optimization/latency/ , and face on "Latency generated by expires", still investigating on that since we use many set expiring many keys

Comment: Just a note - Redis 4 is very old, if possible you should upgrade to get the benefits and security improvements in newer versions.

Comment: @SimonPrickett sure, but I think I need to know the root cause first before upgrade it. we will investigate about "many keys expiring at the same moment can be a source of latency."